# achieving a derived column based on maximal value of subgrouping

Tags: mysql

So I have this MySQL 5.0.24 table

```
select state, county, population from state_pops order by state, county;
```

yields

```
Arizona   Yapavai    4
Arizona   Pueblo     5
Arizona   Pinal      8
Arizona   Maricopa  13
Michigan  Lawson     3
Michigan  Maple      4
Michigan  Appleton   8
Texas     Richmond   5
Texas     Dupree     7
Texas     Brighton  10
```

I need to determine which is the most heavily-populated county in each state.

```
select state, county, max( population) from state_pops group by state order by state;
```

yields

```
Arizona   Maricopa  13
Michigan  Appleton   8
Texas     Brighton  10
```

Easy. But now I need to somehow flag the most-populous county of each state while
listing all counties of all states, like so

```
Arizona   Yapavai    4  NO
Arizona   Pueblo     5  NO
Arizona   Pinal      8  NO
Arizona   Maricopa  13  YES
Michigan  Lawson     3  NO
Michigan  Maple      4  NO
Michigan  Appleton   8  YES
Texas     Richmond   5  NO
Texas     Dupree     7  NO
Texas     Brighton  10  YES
```

So I need to derive a column somehow, perhaps some form of CASE..WHEN Any ideas?

TIA,

Still-learning Stev

Comment: Try using functions the way i explaiend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT a.state, 
       a.county, 
       a.population, 
       COALESCE(b.isMostPop, 'NO') AS flag
FROM state_pops a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT state, MAX(population) AS maxpop, 'YES' AS isMostPop
    FROM state_pops
    GROUP BY state
) b ON a.state = b.state AND a.population = b.maxpop
```

---

**See a [SQL-Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/912a6/1/0)**

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
select state, county, population,heaviest(state,conuty) from state_pops order by state, county;
```

and for that function do this :

```
    create function `heaviest`(`fstate` char(10),`fcounty` char(10))
 RETURNS char(3)

BEGIN

declare ans char(3);


if (select population from yourtable where state=fstate and county=fcounty)>=(select max(population) from yourtable group by state having state=fstate and count=fcount) then set ans='yes';

else set ans='no';

end if;


    return ans;

END;;
```